# A banking function that loops user input and increments/decrements until exit key is entered in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that gives a user 4 choices, does what they choose and then asks them the first 4 choices again and again until they exit.

I have tried using an if/else loop inside a while loop, but that just takes the first user input and loops at that point. It also concatenates the balance when I try to add the two numbers. I assume that due to the fact that the prompt is a string and assigns a string to the variable. I am using console.log() to try and see what is happening while everything is running, but to no avail.

Sorry if this is a lengthy post and redundant.

```
let balance = 0;
let deposit = 0;
let withdraw = 0;

function bankFunction (banked) {
    alert('Hello, how can I help you today?');
    let input = prompt('Q to quit the application \nW to withdraw \nD to deposit \nB to view balance');
    
    while (input != 'Q') {
        if (input === 'W') {
            withdraw = prompt("Withdraw how much?");
            console.log(withdraw);
            balance = balance - withdraw;
            console.log(balance);
        } else if (input === 'D') {
            deposit = prompt("Deposit how much?");
            console.log(deposit);
            balance = balance + withdraw;
            console.log(balance);
        } else {
            alert("done");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this line - `balance = balance + withdraw;` to `balance = balance + parseInt(deposit);` and if value can be of floating type use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: @Abhay, Thank you that works great for adding the number. However, I still get stuck in the if/else answer loop. And my original post was a typo, it should have been balance + deposit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continuously prompt the user for inputs, then the `prompt` function should be inside your loop too. The essential pseudo code is: "While the `input` is not "Q", continue to prompt for a user choice".

Implementation:

```js
let input = "A" // Initial input to get the loop working
while (input !== "Q") {
 // Get actual user input
  input = prompt("Choose Q or W or D or B");
  if (input === "W") {
    // Withdraw logic
  }
  else if (input === "D") {
    // Deposit logic
  } else if (input  === "B") {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Note that there is a bit of a little gimmick here: I needed to have an initial input ("A") to get the first round of the loop working - since in the first round of the loop, user input has not been received yet. Once it get past that initial first round, the `input` variable is being continuously re-assigned through the user prompt, and the loop will exactly how the pseudo-code described it.

If you don't like that gimmick, there is another way, called the While-True-Break loop. The essential idea is that: The loop will automatically run forever, until you explicitly stop it (via `break` statement)

```js
let input;
while (true) {
  input = prompt("Choose Q or W or B or D");
  if (input === "Q") {
    // Stop the program loop
    break;
  } else if (input === "W") {
    // ...
  } else if ...
}
```

Comment: Or use `do{....}while(...)` as that always executes at least once.

Comment: @Michel yeah totally forgot JS has that. I guess I am taking a more language-agnostic approach here.

Comment: *many* languages have a `do{...} while(...)` construct - but no need to make it language-agnostic; the OP tagged this question as JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you all very much! My wall was starting to get a forehead indentation from me/this, so it thanks you too. :)

Comment: The problem with all these solutions is: _under some conditions — for example, when the user switches tabs — the browser may not actually display a dialog, or may not wait for the user to submit text or to cancel the dialog._ ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)) In that case one could get stuck in the loop.